# objC - Semaphore doesn't resume the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, semaphore

So, I am trying to create a small project that tells user how many followers he has.

Currently I'm using Instagram Kit, which uses asynchronous blocks.

My aim is to make program update it's data in the background fetch and change the badge value next to the icon to the number of followers. I had some troubles with the background fetch cause the block that gets the information from instagram completes after the fetch, so no data is retrieved.

I read about semaphores and decided to use them. After i added some code to the method that is called in background fetch, it does the following:

the fetch starts (I get the "We begin" NSLog), then the main thread is freezed by semaphore. It should be resumed by the completition of the "withSuccess"/"failure" part of block. However it gets sucked. And nothing else happens. I am puzzled.

What should I do?

(below is the method that is called during the fetch, I store the instagram-token locally, so no need to request it every time)

```
-(IBAction) backgroundActions {

    NSLog(@"We begin");

    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] getSelfUserDetailsWithSuccess:^(InstagramUser *user) {     
            NSLog(@"%d",user.followedByCount);

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = user.followedByCount;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            localNotification.fireDate = now;
            localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have %d followers.", user.followedByCount];
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =  user.followedByCount;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);


    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

}
```

Comment: You already have a completion block for the network call. What are the semaphores supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is make the asynchronous `getSelfUserDetailsWithSuccess` become synchronous. That is why your main thread is freezing.

Otherwise the code looks fine. What's wrong with removing the semaphore and letting the update happen asynchronously?

Comment: My main aim is to update the badge. If I let the update happen asynchronously, then the fetch it thought to be completed and, as I understood, the application is stopped. The "getSelfUserDetailsWithSuccess" is not ready yet, so, no changes are made.

Comment: The changes will be made when one of the `getSelfUserDetailsWithSuccess` completion blocks is called.

Comment: Without the semaphores, as I've previously tried, the "fetch completed" NSLog is displayed, the app remains closed, but no changes to the badge are made or notifications are shown.